# How do I make my HP G62 function keys work?

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, keyboard, laptop, hp

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.10 (but this problem also appears at 11.04), on my HP g62 laptop, and unfortunately none of the function keys work.

Volume, brightness etc, how can I made them work under Ubuntu?

Comment: I found that the "special" keys worked better when you turned off Action Key mode in the BIOS (on a G72 - presume it's similar) - you have to use the fn key in conjunction, but the volume and media keys started to work. As the answer here explains, currently fn-F2 and fn-F3 don't seem to be registered by the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

### Fn Brightness Keys - Workaround

Currently it is impossible to map the FN keys. Therefore, two utilities for mapping alternative keys are needed so that screen brightness can be adjusted. From terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

Download Ubuntu Tweak from here and install it. Now open Ubuntu Tweak (Application -> System tools) go to the appropriate section (Personal -> Shortcut) and set the combination that you want for example

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>

```
xbacklight -inc 10
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>

```
xbacklight -dec 10
```

To increase and decrease the screen's brightness